# create a field in solr that will index both a double value and the floor of that double value

Tags: solr, lucene

In Solr, is there a way to index a value of type **double**, such that in can be matched on the exact double value and the floor of that value? For example:

given the indexed value: **12.34**

- query value: 12.34 = matched
- query value: 12 = matched
- query value: 1234 = not matched
- query value: 12.3 = not matched

It would be nice if range queries could still be used as well.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but why don't you store the value as an integer and then compare with the floor of any input you have?

Comment: How are documents getting into your index? do you have an ingestion pipeline of some sort handy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these options :-

1. If you are feeding the data, handle it on the client side to index it as a multivalued field with both the values, the double as well as the rounded one
2. If you are using DIH you can easily use the [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to convert it into multivalued fields

Example -

Data Config - Add custom field -

```
<script><![CDATA[
        function addfield(row){
            var fieldName = row.get('double_value');
    // Round it
            row.put(fieldName, double_rounded);
            return row;
        }
]]></script>
```

1. Else, just write a Custom filter which would store both the Original token and the Rounded value in the index.

With the fields being Mark Float, the Range Queries also should work fine.